# Sonarqube. I cannot Edit a rule. Still Working is frozen

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

I have a production instance of SonarQube v5.1.1 (with a Postgres database). When I try to modify a Rule, some of them, shows "Still Working...", but nothing happens.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHXaB.jpg)

Also sonar.log is not showing any activity.

Any ideas of what happend?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the browser or opening the same URL in a new window/tab? This sounds like a client-side display glitch.

Comment: When i click the rule (e.g.: 'Loggers should be "private static final" and should share a naming convention') this action not generate any url in the browser, therefore i can't reload. Besides this issue occurs in differents browsers and differents machines.